# What diameter pipe should I run from a septic pump up hill (3 meter head ) to my septic tank?

Tags: plumbing

what diameter pipe should I run from a septic pump up hill (3 meter head ) to my septic tank please

Comment: Locating a septic tank ABOVE the level of the house seems like a very, very bad idea.

Comment: You really should reconsider position of septic tank.If you decide to keep it up hill you should know that normally when people use pumps for sewerage they usually have 2 pumps; if one stops working the other one automatically starts. But PLEASE don't do that.

Comment: I would also think a backwater valve would be an essential backup device in this situation, though if it did ever backup, I'm not sure how you'd "reset" it for use again, as you'd have all the waste water in the uphill pipe holding it shut with nowhere to drain to. Anyone care to weigh in on this? Can a backwater valve be installed at the septic tank at the top of the hill? Quick search doesn't really find anything about this (probably because a septic tank uphill is just a Bad Idea in general..).

Answer (score 1):

The pump and pipe (force main, being on the far side of the pump) size should be specified by your septic system engineering documents. While I feel similar to the commentators about pumping sewage, sometimes it's the only way (house on a lake, for instance.)

I would strongly suggest both the "two pump and alarm" method (preferably with a pump controller that uses both pumps in an alternating fashion - having a "spare" sit there while the main pump works tends to lead to having two pumps that don't work when the main one breaks) and a mounting method that permits the pump to be pulled out for service (typically the pump is on rails, and the system automatically valves off the pipe when the pump is pulled out.) They are disgusting and expensive enough to repair without setting them up in a manner that requires a pump out and someone going into the hole to fix them.